# Using Azure HDInsight and Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, azure-cloud-services, azure-hdinsight, azure-powershell

I have created an HDInsight cluster but wants to upload a database on portal and use hive on it. What are the steps i need to take?

I know how to use hive but don't know how to connect the data being uploaded in container blob and hive. Btw I am using Powershell

Answer (score 0):

Need to link storage account of the container with hdinsight cluster.
To do that, add following property in core-site.xml

```
<property>
        <name>fs.azure.account.key.[STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME].blob.core.windows.net</name>
        <value>[STORAGE ACCOUNT KEY]</value>
</property>
```

Once its linked, you will be to access that storage account.
To Create hive table on data residing in blob, use external hive table with location pointing to blob directory of your data.

example : CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE (col1 datatype, ....)
          ROW  FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
          Location 'wasb://@.blob.core.windows.net/PATH/OF/DATA/'